# Naming convention for environment variables files?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, naming-conventions

I was just wondering if there was any standardized convention for `.env` environment variable files. If I had multiple setups (e.g. `development`, `staging`, `production`), what should they be titled?

I've seen:

- `.env.development`, ...
- `development.env`, ...
- `settings.development.env`, ...
- `.env`, `.env.staging`, `.env.production`, ...

If there isn't a standard, are there arguments for which to use (kinda like `""` vs `''` for strings in JS)? Which do you use and why?

Comment: Specifically, is there any reasoning against using multiple `.`s, like `.env.debug.prod`. Is it going to affect your terminal commands containing `--env .env.*`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I prefer `.env` at the end ex: `.production.env` because last word after . indicates extension. VSCode does not recognize the file as .env file if you do `.env.production`

VSCode Documentation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variables

Answer (score 15):

I'm using this convention since I can't find any other suggestions: https://rubyonjets.com/docs/env-files/

```
.env
.env.development
.env.test
.env.production
```

I like maintaining the .env at the front and this seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 10):

There is only one standard in node ecosystem - use `production` in `NODE_ENV` variable for production. It's used by different tools for optimizing.

The rest is on you. But personally, I don't see reasons to make it complex. If you need to differentiate instances further than just `production`, `development`, you can use other environment variables.

Also you need to be careful when using different `NODE_ENV` for staging and production. Because the main purpose of staging is to test everything as close to production as possible. So changing `NODE_ENV` can be a reason to production fail.

Comment: Thanks for the `NODE_ENV` info, but is there any other convention for the actual file name as well?