# Different .env content for development and production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a `.env` file (I am using next.js and node.js, where each have their own `.env`), where some content are different for development and deployment.

For development:

```
DOMAIN_URL=https://localhost:3000
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='abc'
```

For deployment:

```
DOMAIN_URL=https://www.example.com
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID='def'
```

I hope to make it easy by setting a flag say
`DEV_FLAG=dev` or `DEV_FLAG=production`
and according to the `DEV_FLAG` the `.env` can be set accordingly,

1. but how to use if condition in `.env` file?
2. Or if there is a better way to set the `.env` for different context?

Comment: Create a different .env file per context. `.env.local` for local, and `.env.production` for production?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Naming convention for environment variables files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55458239/naming-convention-for-environment-variables-files)

Comment: Actually I prefer to keep one env file, since there is a lot of commonality @evolutionxbox

Comment: Env files are just plain text. They cannot contain logic

Answer (score 4):

`.env` file is not meant to be commited in repo. It is meant to be added before running app. It should be ignored by VCS by adding `.env` line to `.gitignore` or `.hgignore` file.

`.env` file contains potentially secret values and you don't want to have them in repo for everyone to see.

You can commit `example.env` for deployers to see which env variables are available. Deployer/DevOp will run `cp example.env .env`, then edit `.env` file and run application.

You can commit `default.env` and load it in application before loading `.env` file for some sane not secret default values for tests or some generic (localhost) deploy environment.

But `.env` file should be original in each deploy.

You could set some flag `DEV_FLAG=dev` or `DEV_FLAG=prod` and in application change some behaviour based on its value, but generally I would not recommend it because it hides consequences.

Maybe you are developing on one pc and want to switch `.env` values. You can have more lines in file and comment them out as needed or you can have `prod.env` or `local.env` files and `cp local.env .env` as needed while having them ignored in `.gitignore`.

More about this topic you can read here: https://www.12factor.net/config